# Android - Hook Notifications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Is there any way to *do something* when the phone **receives a notification** from any other App? (I don't care about the content of the notification)

I would to change the default notification sound of the device (every time a new notification appears)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here an Example :

```
    protected void GenerateNotify() {

        NotificationManager myNotificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
        Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now,"hi",100);
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),as.class);
        PendingIntent contentintent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Hi","date", contentintent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
```

Before doing this please put mp3 file into raw folder and navigate it to correct path

Comment: This code is to create a new notification, it's not my goal, i would "hook all others", and at each hook trigger the code to change the default system notification sound